# Sitecore WFFM-Webforms customize html structure

Tags: sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I am Using WFFM with Sitecore-8.2-Update 4 Version. So i have a requirement to change HTML structure of WFFM webforms.

Let me share my case.

We have Name Section that contains first name and last name.

IN WFFM form designer i have created like below

[image]

Then the Html is generated like below by WFFM.

```html
<div class="required-field  form-group">
    <input id="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156_Sections_0__Fields_0__Id" name="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156.Sections[0].Fields[0].Id" type="hidden" value="{6DAF46AC-CEE6-4CB2-9391-40ACC39CCE74}" />
    <label class="control-label" for="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156_Sections_0__Fields_0__Value">LastName</label>
    <input class=" form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The LastName field must be a string with a minimum length of 0 and a maximum length of 256." data-val-length-max="256" data-val-required="This field is required." data-val-required-tracking="{7E86B2F5-ACEC-4C60-8922-4EB5AE5D9874}" id="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156_Sections_0__Fields_0__Value" name="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156.Sections[0].Fields[0].Value" placeholder="" style="" type="text" value="" /><span class="field-validation-valid help-block" data-valmsg-for="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156.Sections[0].Fields[0].Value" data-valmsg-replace="true">
</span>
</div>
<div class="required-field  form-group">
    <input id="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156_Sections_0__Fields_1__Id" name="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156.Sections[0].Fields[1].Id" type="hidden" value="{FF409749-4574-4D8C-971D-1A2D66B82FDA}" />
    <label class="control-label" for="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156_Sections_0__Fields_1__Value">FirstName</label>
    <input class=" form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The FirstName field must be a string with a minimum length of 0 and a maximum length of 256." data-val-length-max="256" data-val-required="This field is required." data-val-required-tracking="{7E86B2F5-ACEC-4C60-8922-4EB5AE5D9874}" id="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156_Sections_0__Fields_1__Value" name="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156.Sections[0].Fields[1].Value" placeholder="" style="" type="text" value="" /><span class="field-validation-valid help-block" data-valmsg-for="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156.Sections[0].Fields[1].Value" data-valmsg-replace="true">
</span>
</div>
```

But I need a Html like below one

```html
<div class="required-field  form-group has-feedback">
  <span>
    <input class=" form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The First field must be a string with a minimum length of 0 and a maximum length of 256." data-val-length-max="256" data-val-required="This field is required." data-val-required-tracking="{7E86B2F5-ACEC-4C60-8922-4EB5AE5D9874}" id="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156_Sections_0__Fields_1__Value" name="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156.Sections[0].Fields[1].Value" placeholder="" style="" type="text" value="">
    <input id="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156_Sections_0__Fields_1__Id" name="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156.Sections[0].Fields[1].Id" type="hidden" value="{FF409749-4574-4D8C-971D-1A2D66B82FDA}">
    <label class="control-label" for="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156_Sections_0__Fields_1__Value">First</label>
    <span class="field-validation-valid help-block" data-valmsg-for="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156.Sections[0].Fields[1].Value" data-valmsg-replace="true">
    </span>
  </span>
  <span>
    <input class=" form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The Last field must be a string with a minimum length of 0 and a maximum length of 256." data-val-length-max="256" data-val-required="This field is required." data-val-required-tracking="{7E86B2F5-ACEC-4C60-8922-4EB5AE5D9874}" id="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156_Sections_0__Fields_0__Value" name="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156.Sections[0].Fields[0].Value" placeholder="" style="" type="text" value="">
    <input id="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156_Sections_0__Fields_0__Id" name="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156.Sections[0].Fields[0].Id" type="hidden" value="{6DAF46AC-CEE6-4CB2-9391-40ACC39CCE74}">
    <label class="control-label" for="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156_Sections_0__Fields_0__Value">Last</label>
    <span class="field-validation-valid help-block" data-valmsg-for="wffm26cf3ccb39024ed0974e0f60d9292156.Sections[0].Fields[0].Value" data-valmsg-replace="true">
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

**Steps that i followed change html structure of WFFM.**

1. WFFM using Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Controllers.FormController and Its using default index action. By this it is using ~\Views\Forms\Index.cshtml on root web site.

[image]

2. Its basically using Editor for template.

[image]

3. So in my case i need to find out name section and need to change my html structure. From my findings SectionViewModel.cshtml is responsible for rendering all sections.

I have create one method to check whether current section needs to customized or not.

> @if
>   (Renderer.IsCustomisedSection(Model))

Below my full SectionViewModel view file. (~\Views\Form\EditorTemplates\SectionViewModel.cshtml)

```html
@using Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Html
@using AAA.Foundation.HtmlHelper.WffmRenderer;
@model Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.ViewModels.SectionViewModel

<!--Render customised action-->
@if (Renderer.IsCustomisedSection(Model))
{
    var customisedFieldHtml = Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Fields);
    @Html.Raw(Renderer.RenderCustomisedFieldSection(customisedFieldHtml))
}
else
    <!--Render customised action Ends-->
if (Model.ShowTitle && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Title))
{
    <fieldset class="@Model.CssClass">
        <legend>@Html.BootstrapText("Title")</legend>
        @if (Model.ShowInformation && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Information))
        {
            <p>@Html.BootstrapText("Information")</p>
        }

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Fields)
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}

else
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Fields)
}
```

4. This is how i can catch Name section by model title.Below my renderer class file

   ```
       public static bool IsCustomisedSection(Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.ViewModels.SectionViewModel model) {
           bool result = false;

           // Check the model needs to customised                 
           if (model.Title == "Name") { // For Ex:
               result = true;
           }

           return result;
       }
   ```
5. Then i will call respective customize html section like below.

> var customisedFieldHtml = Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Fields);
>       @Html.Raw(Renderer.RenderCustomisedFieldSection(customisedFieldHtml))

6. Using "Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Fields)" this i can get default generated html. Then i will pass it to my customise render method. This will identify which sites and which section rendere needs to apply.

   ```
       public static HtmlString RenderCustomisedFieldSection(HtmlString 
       customisedSectionHtml)         
       {
       string caseValue = "SiteName-SectionName";        
       HtmlString result = new HtmlString(string.Empty);        
       switch (caseValue)          {

       case "SiteName-SectionName":
       result = SiteName_Renderer.NameSection(customisedSectionHtml);
       break;
       }    
       return result;    
       }
   ```
7. My final customised html rendere method like below. I am using html agility pack to reframe the htmls.

   ```
    public static HtmlString NameSection(HtmlString rawHtml)
       {

           HtmlNode customisedRoot = null;
           HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
           doc.LoadHtml(rawHtml.ToString());

           // Find each form group elements
           var groupHtml = doc.DocumentNode
               .Descendants("div")
               .Where(d =>
                  d.Attributes.Contains("class")
                  &&
                  d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("form-group")
               );

           if (groupHtml.Count() > 0)
           {
               // Initialise root
               customisedRoot = groupHtml.First().Clone();
               customisedRoot.RemoveAllChildren();

               // Customised the html
               foreach (HtmlNode htmlNode in groupHtml)
               {
                   HtmlDocument innerRootDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                   HtmlNode innerRoot = innerRootDoc.CreateElement("span");


                   var helpBlock = htmlNode.Descendants("span").Where(d =>
                     d.Attributes.Contains("class")
                     &&
                     d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("help-block")
                  );
                   innerRoot.PrependChild(helpBlock.FirstOrDefault());


                   var label = htmlNode.Descendants("label");
                   innerRoot.PrependChild(label.FirstOrDefault());


                   var inputs = htmlNode.Descendants("input");
                   foreach (HtmlNode inputsNode in inputs)
                   {
                       innerRoot.PrependChild(inputsNode);

                   }

                   customisedRoot.PrependChild(innerRoot);
               }
           }

    return (customisedRoot!=null)?new HtmlString(customisedRoot.OuterHtml):          new HtmlString(String.Empty);
    }
   ```

By this approach i can able to customize WFFM web form html.

Below are i have tested after my html changes.

1. Does validation working or not in website.
2. If i submit the form will it available in form-reports section.In download excel whether submitted value will present or not.

So all the above cases or passed.

My query is above approach will break any other functionality.

Comment: I think no one has answered cause the question is really long and lacks a quick point that people can grasp... understanding your question should be in its own stackoverflow question.